# Who can make this JPQL Query?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

My JPA-entity classes look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long id;

...

    // bi-directional many-to-many association to Tag
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_tags_preferences", joinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id") })
    private List<Tag> tags;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tags")
public class Tag implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

...

    // bi-directional many-to-many association to CookEvent
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
    private List<CookEvent> cookEvents;

    // bi-directional many-to-many association to User
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
    private List<User> users;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cook_events")
public class CookEvent implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "takes_place_on")
    private LocalDateTime takesPlaceOn;

...

    // bi-directional many-to-many association to Tag
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "cook_events_tags", joinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(name = "cook_event_id") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id") })
    @OrderBy("name")
    private List<Tag> tags;
```

In my database I thus have 'users', 'cook_events', 'tags', 'user_tags_preferences', 'cook_events_tags' tables. 
I would need to make a JPQL query that does following:

From my front-end I have the user_id.
I would like a query that filters all cook_events that are `takesPlaceOn > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, and where at least one of the user_tags_preferences from my user_id matches the cook_event_tags.

Is there a possibility with joins to filter all this to ultimately just get a `List<CookEvent>` I need. Or even a `List<Tag>` if it's easier.

It can even be different queries and that I filter it myself in the backend, but I would like to try to filter everything within a query.

Answer (score 0):

Could this just be the answer?

```
SELECT DISTINCT(c) from User u JOIN u.tags t JOIN t.cookEvents c
WHERE u.id = :id AND c.takesPlaceOn > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1.
Replace **List** in all your many-to-many associations with **Set**.

Step 2.
Change the JPQL query to:
SELECT c from CookEvent c JOIN FETCH c.tags t JOIN FETCH t.users u WHERE c.takesPlaceOn > 
 CURRENT_TIMESTAMP And u.id = :id